# How can my app track specific phone downloads?

Tags: android, ios

I want to give free stuffs for first time users.

How am I able to track that your phone (both iOS and Android) is downloading my app for the very first time and not deleted and re-downloaded, for iOS and Android?

Comment: use user accounts. if the user is sign in, save a counter in the db. if that counter is 0, then give them something, otherwise, dont.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you store device UDID/UUID in both cases and make a counter in backend database for install times associated with this UDID/UUID if the counter equal to one then this is first time user if more than that then this user has deleted and redownloaded the app. For iOS an additional step is required as the UDID is an generated value. You will have to save this in the keychain. Keychain won't get cleared when you uninstall the app. It will though if you reset your phone.